# Workbox service worker only registering routes when CORS is turned off

Tags: reactjs, django, cors, service-worker, workbox

I have a django/react app that is trying to use a service worker to allow precaching and offline operations. Specifically, I am using Workbox. It's actually working fairly well, except the ability to work offline. The service worker's file is located, the service worker installs without issue, and even precaches all necessary files. When I start in a chrome browser with all history/cache emptied, it starts up decently

Service worker is installed on application tab:

Manifest is present on the application tab

And we even have precached files on the application tab. There is a log in the console from workbox that says six files are precached

However, if we reload the page (which is necessary to get the routing) Workbox does not detect any routes

And it doesn't work when you set it to offline in the network tab

HOWEVER, if I disable web security/CORS in chrome with this command

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\chromeTemp`

Everything else works the same, just the registering of routes and offline operations works fine. The service worker starts, installs, and precaches the same. The manifest is detected. But, on second load, the console logs that workbox has routes, and that they match the requests.
When we set it to offline and refresh the URL, the registered routes detects that the browser is offline but it has a route, and we get no error

My service worker file is as such:

```
import { clientsClaim } from 'workbox-core';
import { ExpirationPlugin } from 'workbox-expiration';
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from 'workbox-precaching';
import { registerRoute, NavigationRoute, Route } from 'workbox-routing';
import { StaleWhileRevalidate, CacheFirst } from 'workbox-strategies';

clientsClaim();

console.log('precacheAndRoute', location);
precacheAndRoute([
  {url: location.origin + '/meterqc', revision: '383676'},
  {url: 'http://localhost:3000/staticfiles/bundles/MeterQC.js', revision: '383676'},

  {url: location.origin + '/meterqc/logo192.png', revision: '383676'},
  {url: location.origin + '/meterqc/logo512.png', revision: '383676'},
  {url: location.origin + '/meterqc/favicon.ico', revision: '383676'},
  {url: location.origin + '/meterqc/manifest.json', revision: '383676'}
]);

const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp('/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$');

registerRoute(
  ({ request, url }) => {
    console.log('registerRoute');
    if (request.mode !== 'navigate') {
      return false;
    } // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.
    if (url.pathname.startsWith('/_')) {
      return false;
    } // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains // a file extension, skip.
    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    } // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.

    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(location.origin + '/meterqc')
);

registerRoute(
  ({ url }) => url.origin === self.location.origin && url.pathname.endsWith('.png'), // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'images',
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 }),
    ],
  })
);
console.log("Finished");
```

And it is registered in my index.jsx like this:

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const swPath = window.location.origin + '/meterqc/MeterQCOffline.js';
    navigator.serviceWorker.register(swPath).then(registration => {
      navigator.serviceWorker.ready
        .then(function (registration) {
        });
    }).catch(registrationError => {
      console.log('SW registration failed: ', registrationError);
    });
  });
}
else{
  console.log('unable to register service worker');
}
```

I've ripped my app down to studs and still it's doing this. The only reason I stumbled on turning CORS off was because before i reproduced it locally, we were using a github pipeline to deploy to an azure app service that had Cloudflare as a CDN. Intermittent CORS errors popped up because of the interplay between Cloudflare and Azure, but I noticed it worked fine when CORS was turned off. I then removed everything, and reproduced on localhost, and it continues to do the same thing.

The first registerRoute has a function as it's first argument, which has this:
`({ request, url }) => { console.log('registerRoute');`

When CORS is turned off, this log fires, and also registerRoute appears to work. When it's on, we never get this log, implying that it isn't failing, it just isn't firing at all. There are also no errors, aside from a favicon error that happens in both setups

Does anyone know what Chrome browser security could be blocking Workbox from registering Routes?

If anyone can help it would greatly appreciated. I will be turning a working example of this into a github repo with install instructions over the next day.

Completely removed azure, oauth login against ADFS, cloudflare. Removed all apps and removed any references to CORS in my settings file. Removed extra React stuff my organization had on top of the hello world pictured above. I ran Chrome with

"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-web-security --user-data-dir=%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\chromeTemp

and everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

So, while I didn't figure out exactly why this is happening, but it turns out my development computer is the only place this is happening. My coworkers have no issue with this, either on localhost or deployed to azure app services. So, if you have this specific issue, deploy it to a server and try a different computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).